# How to update context after user authentication

Tags: authentication, graphql, react-apollo

I have be struggling with an authentication problem for hours. I log in successfully from React front end, but I am not able to update the headers with a token in the context. After login, I need to refresh the page to successfully query the logged user. The setContext function gets run before the login function updates the token in the localStorage.

I have tried also making the query with `client.query({ query: LOGGED_USER })` in a `useEffect` hook, but the outcome is the same. I always need to refresh the page before the `LOGGED_USER` returns something other than `null`.

```
INDEX.JS
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
})

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {

  // After login this function is run. The problem is that at that point
  // there is still token in the local storage and therefore the authorization
  // header is null.

  const token = localStorage.getItem('library-user-token')
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `bearer ${token}` : null,
    }
  }
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'))


APP.JS
const LOGIN = gql`
  mutation login($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(
      username: $username,
      password: $password
    ) {
      value
    }
  }
`

const LOGGED_USER = gql`
  {
    me {
      username
      favoriteGenre
    }
  }
`

const App = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState('authors')
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null)
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState(null)
  const loggedUserResult = useQuery(LOGGED_USER)
  const authorResult = useQuery(ALL_AUTHORS)
  const bookResult = useQuery(ALL_BOOKS)
  const client = useApolloClient()

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(localStorage.getItem('library-user-token'))
  }, [])

  const login = useMutation(LOGIN)

  return (
    <div>
      <LoginForm
        show={page === 'login'}
        login={login}
        setToken={(token) => setToken(token)}
        setPage={setPage}
      />
    </div>
  )
}


LOGINFORM.JS
const LoginForm = (props) => {
  if (!props.show) {
    return null
  }

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const loginUser = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    try {
      const result = await props.login({
        variables: { username, password }
      })

      // Context updates here so the token is not yet is the localStorage and
      // therefore LOGGED_USER query returns null

      const token = result.data.login.value
      props.setToken(token)
      localStorage.setItem('library-user-token', token)
      await props.login({
        variables: { username, password }
      })
      props.setToken(token)
      props.setPage('authors')
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

What would be the correct way to query the logged user from the database without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify and set the token in the request headers, you can use a middleware, in such a way [Apollo docs suggested](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication/#header):

> Another common way to identify yourself when using HTTP is to send along an authorization header. It's easy to add an authorization header to every HTTP request by chaining together Apollo Links. In this example, we'll pull the login token from localStorage every time a request is sent:

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: '/graphql',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "",
    }
  }
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

I'm following the same setup in my GraphQL apps.